# Unable to increase PHP Memory Limit

Tags: php, apache, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am running into an issue with a project I am working with on my localhost, where I am unable to increase the PHP memory_limit setting.

I've tried increasing it directly in the **php.ini** config:

`memory_limit = 1024M`

I've tried increasing it in the projects **.htaccess** file:

`php_value memory_limit 1024M`

I've tried increasing it directly in the function of the PHP controller:

`ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');`

Yet none of these actually increases the memory limit for the project, and echoing out `phpinfo()` confirms that the memory_limit has not been changed.

I've checked the **Loaded Configuration File** setting in `phpinfo()` to ensure that I modified the correct **php.ini** file, and that no other additional config files are being parsed, that could conflict with this setting, but I am still unable to get the setting to increase.

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php5/apache2
>
> Loaded Configuration File /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
>
> Scan this dir for additional .ini files   /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
>
> Additional .ini files parsed  /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini,
> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini,
> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-memcached.ini,
> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini,
> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini

Any ideas from the community as to what else I could try? I am using **PHP v5.5.9**.

Comment: the .htaccess should have overwritten the apache config settings, but you might want to try increasing defaults there too.  I've never run into that.

Comment: Did you restart Apache after you changed the php.ini?

Comment: What's your version of PHP? Short notation such as "1024M" is only available since 5.1.0 and can be used only in php.ini (http://php.net/manual/en/faq.using.php#faq.using.shorthandbytes). You can try to write it in bytes 1073741824.

Comment: Yes, I restarted Apache after the changes. I'm using PHP v5.5.9

Comment: Are you using ini_get to read the memory limit or waiting for an error? Have you checked for auto-prepends? Overrides elsewhere in the code? BTW increasing the memory allocation, especially to such a large value should be a last-resort, even if you're using cackePHP.

Comment: Thanks @symcbean! So it looks like the memory limit was being increased properly. The reason it was not reflecting in the phpinfo(), is because I was making the memory increase in the controller, and then echoing phpinfo() from the view, so the increase was not reflected in the view. Using ini_get() helped me trace the memory limit across the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the memory limit was being increased properly, just not being reflected in **phpinfo()**. The reason it was not reflecting in the **phpinfo()** echo, is because I was making the memory increase in the controller, and then echoing phpinfo() from the view, so the increase was not being reflected in the view.

Using `ini_get()` helped me trace the memory limit across the request.